# how to show dashboard with reverse proxy in grafana

Tags: nginx, grafana

I have put grafana behind reverse proxy with nginx, when I send a request for dashboard content with a angular4 client like this:

```
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({"Authorization": 'Bearer eyJrIjoia3FFZGFRcjU2WmY3c1doNE1FS0h4NlpMVXdTU2haQTEiLCJuIjoidGVzdCIsImlkIjoxfQ=='});
this.http.get("http://172.16.0.44/d/Zadt1Tgiz/test?orgId=1&from=1510888599469&to=1512033399469&kiosk",
{headers:headers,responseType:'text'}).subscribe(
  res =>{
    document.getElementById("dash").innerHTML=res;
  },
  error=>{
    console.error(error);
  }
)
```

then the "dash" area show like this:
[dash area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlzrJ.png)

the js file or css file is not loaded correctly, which is loaded from localhost not from grafana server.

how to let the js and css loaded from grafana server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/behind_proxy/). There's detailed setup instructions including nginx.

Comment: yeah, maybe there was some incorrectly configuration with nginx or grafana, which made js file or css file loaded from localhost. I have checked many times, but didn't find anythind wrong. then i solved it by adding a filter on my localhost server , when the request is about grafana, i will forward the request to grafana server, thanks for your answer

Comment: oh, god, i kown what was wrong, i change the configuration in grafana.ini, but the configuration in this file is commented , i have not uncommented them!

Comment: Hi Vivien, how do u set your grafana behind the proxy?